# What visa should one apply for if they want to become partners in a UK firm?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, immigration

Suppose that a person is an  international student wanting to invest in an existing firm in UK. Which visa types could such a person  opt for and what advantages would each type have over a skilled worker visa?

Suppose the person is hoping to obtain ILR (indefinite leave to remain) in the future. Does one type of visa offer a faster route to ILR than another does?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that one does not need to be physically present in the UK to **invest** in a UK firm, and thus no visa at all is required for an investor.

Legally, I understand, one need not be present in the UK to be a partner (in a firm structured as a partnership) and some partnerships are in fact international. A partner who is not present in the UK would not need any UK visa. However, the nature of partnership duties might well require physical presence, and indeed a firm might be unwilling to accept as a partner, a person who could not guarantee long-term presence in the UK, and thus such firms might require ILR or a similar status to have been achieved **before** admitting that person to partnership.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I really appreciate it.